# JQuery Plugin Mask não funciona

Tags: jquery

Gostaria de adicionar uma máscara para o cadastro de telefone fixo, numa tela do sistema. Porém o JQuery não está funcionando. Segue código abaixo.

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tel').mask('(00)0000-0000');
    });
```

Adicionei isso no footer.php e a chamada da biblioteca está no header.php. Já tentei colocar ambos (chamada e script) no próprio formulário mas também não surte efeito.

Comment: Aparece erro no console?

Comment: Esse `#tel` é um input text?

Comment: Não aparece erro no console, @Sam

Comment: Sim, é o id de um input text

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde.

Verifique se a chamada do jQuery está antes da chamada da biblioteca jQueryMask.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.js"></script>
```

Verifique também se está fechando a tag de script no final

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tel').mask('(00)0000-0000');
});
</script>
```

E lembrando também que o script deve vir depois da chamadas das bibliotecas.

Caso isso não ajude, poste mais trechos do código para verificarmos.